# Mapreducing to count the occurrence of fields that may or may not exist

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mapreduce

This gives me an error of {"assertion"=>"map invoke failed: JS Error: ReferenceError: foo is not defined nofile_b:4".  Any ideas?

```
class ObjResults
  include Mongoid::Document

field :foo, :type => Boolean, :default => false 
field :bar, :type => Boolean, :default => false 

def self.stats_by_user_id user_id
 map = <<-MAP
 function() { 
    if (this.user_id == "#{user_id}") {   
        hsh = {}    
        if (this.foo) {
            hsh["foo"] = this.foo
            }
        if (this.bar) {
            hsh["bar"] = this.bar
        }
        emit(this.user_id, hsh);  
    }
} 
MAP
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put foo and bar in quotes when assigning to the hash:

```
hsh["foo"] = this.foo;  // or hsh.foo = this.foo
```

You might consider tagging this question as javascript since the ruby portion is minimal.

Answer (score 0):

The JavaScript looks fine to me but perhaps MongoDB is adding extra restrictions which lead to the strange error message. I can think of two things you can try: use `hasOwnProperty` to see if `foo` and `bar` are there:

```
map = <<-MAP
 function() { 
    if (this.user_id == "#{user_id}") {   
        hsh = { };
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('foo')) {
            hsh["foo"] = this.foo;
        }
        if (this.hasOwnProperty('bar')) {
            hsh["bar"] = this.bar;
        }
        emit(this.user_id, hsh);  
    }
} 
MAP
```

or use the bracket notation for accessing the properties of `this`:

```
map = <<-MAP
 function() { 
    if (this.user_id == "#{user_id}") {   
        hsh = { };
        if (typeof this['foo'] != 'undefined') {
            hsh["foo"] = this.foo;
        }
        if (typeof this['bar'] != 'undefined') {
            hsh["bar"] = this.bar;
        }
        emit(this.user_id, hsh);  
    }
} 
MAP
```

Note that I've tightened up the logic in this one to see if `foo` and `bar` are there rather than just checking their truthiness.

Comment: I ended up just going back to trying:

emit(this.user_id, {foo: this.foo, bar: this.bar})

That hadn't worked the first time, but now does?  So I guess all the extra code was not needed.  Thanks anyway though!

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to reproduce your problem. However, Just for practice issue, I write below code which runs well. I just hope this still helpful.

command line:

```
2.0.0p0 :023 > Band.all.to_a.map(&:bar)
=> [false, false, true, false]
2.0.0p0 :024 > Band.all.to_a.map(&:foo)
=> [false, false, true, true]
2.0.0p0 :025 > Band.mar.to_a
=> [{"_id"=>"Apple", "value"=>{"likes"=>888.0, "hh"=>3.0}}, {"_id"=>"IBM", "value"=>{"likes"=>1431.0, "hh"=>0.0}}]
```

code structure:

```
class Band
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :name, type: String
  field :likes, type: Integer, default: 0
  field :foo, type: Boolean, default: false
  field :bar, type: Boolean, default: false

  def self.mar
    map = %Q{
      function() {
        hsh = {};
        if(this.foo) {hsh.foo = this.foo}
        if(this.bar) {hsh.bar = this.bar}
        emit(this.name, { likes: this.likes, hh: hsh });
      }
    }

    reduce = %Q{
      function(key, values) {
        var result = { likes: 0, hh: 0 };
        values.forEach(function(value) {
          result.likes += value.likes;
          if(value.hh.foo) {result.hh += 1}
          if(value.hh.bar) {result.hh += 1}

        });
        return result;
      }
    }

    self.where(:likes.gt => 100).map_reduce(map, reduce).out(inline: true)
  end
end
```